# This is duplicating the items

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

```
SELECT qi.ItemNo
    ,ISNULL(qi.description, '') AS Description
    ,ISNULL(qi.Qty, 0) AS Qty
    ,qi.Price 
    ,SUM(qi.Qty * qi.Price) AS ExtPrice
FROM dbo.QuoteItem qi (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Quote q (NOLOCK)
        ON (qi.QuoteNo = q.QuoteNo)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Inventory i (NOLOCK) 
        ON (qi.serialno = i.serialno)
WHERE 
    q.SalesNo = '2328719529'
    AND m.itemtype NOT IN ('L','F','S')
    AND qi.warrantyflag <> 'Y'
    AND qi.ITEMTYPE NOT IN ('SUBHEAD','COMMENT','BLANK','SUBTOTAL')
    AND qi.statuscode NOT IN ('CANCELLED','CANCELED')
    AND q.statuscode NOT IN ('CLOSED')
    AND ISNULL(m.prodtype,'')=''
    AND isNull(qi.Printflag, '') = 'Y'
GROUP BY qi.ConItemNo 
        ,qi.Description 
        ,qi.Qty
        ,qi.Price 
    WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY qi.ConItemNo DESC
```

This is the result set that I am expecting

[image]

```
ConItemNo       Description     Qty     Price       ExtPrice        Format
1               test1           1       100         100     
2               test2           2       200         400     
3               test3           3       300         900     
4               test4           1       100         100     
5               test5           2       100         200     
                Subtotal                            1700             B
                Total                               1700             U,B
```

Any suggestions? The column 'Format' does not belong to any table, it is added after. I was thinking about adding the QuoteItems to a temp table and modifying the data after. I'm just not sure how to go about this. Any advice will be very much appreciated. I am trying to accomplish this in Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have four group by keys, why would you expect only two additional rows for the rollup?  Apart from that, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: You might take a peek at this too before you continue that nolock hint. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: This website has a great example of how you can find the answer to this problem. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Where is the duplicate?

Comment: @SeanLange What is so bad about NOLOCK? The entire system I'm working on has stored procs everywhere that make use of NOLOCK? Haven't had an issue in the 10+ years it was running. I'm not disagreeing with what your saying. I seen many people say NOLOCK is dangerous but our system haven't had an issue with it as of yet. In fact we ran into deadlocks before when we didn't have NOLOCK. I just fail to see the issue with NOLOCK. I'm still newbie at SQL so I'm not arguing with you or anything, I'm just hoping to understand better. I started SQL like 4 months ago, i think i advanced at a fair rate.

Comment: Did you read the article I shared? Accuracy is one of the biggest issues. You can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows when using nolock. If that system has nolock on every single query I am certain there have been issues as a result but probably not resolved issues because they are impossible to replicate consistently. It is not a magic go faster button with no ramifications. If that were the case all queries would just work like that.